# C++ #pragma comment(lib...) Java equivalent?

Tags: java, eclipse, static-libraries

I'm curious if it's possible to have the equivalent of C++ #pragma comment(lib...) in Java.

I have a project with a Lib X with some feature.  And I want to build the project with and without the library.  Since we don't have preprocessor in Java, it's probably not possible.

In Eclipse, it's possible without creating 2 different projects?

Thanks

Comment: I don't know of any equivalents in Java, but the same can probably be achieved by using std. OO-principles instead, possibly combined with reflection. Is this a Java library (jar) or a native one (lib/dll)?

Comment: Why do you mean by std?  Reflection would probably work, but I need a way to include/exclude the lib.  It's a jar.

Comment: I think you can't do it this way, but instead can't you create a factory LibXInstanceFactory ? In a case (depending on your conf) the LibXInstanceFactory.getInstance() can return a "true" instance of your object using your lib, in the other case, it would return an "empty" instance of a class that would implement the same interface or override the other. It can apply to you ?

Comment: Yes, that was exactly my point. Use some kind of factory to retrieve an instance, and it can instantiate the library instance using reflection, or some dummy/mock instance if it is not available at runtime -- or even through an exception if that's preferable. If you want, I can write up a more detailed suggestion as an answer.

Comment: I like the solution with runtime library instantiation.  I never did that in java, but I'll search.  You can post it as an answer (no need for a detailed answer)